# How to register Spring Data Mongo MBeans using Spring Java Configuration?

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-data-mongodb, spring-jmx

I would like to enable the registration of the Mongo JMX MBeans as described in the [Spring Data MongoDB Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#mongo.jmx), not using the JMX configuration, but in Java. So I look for the corresponding Java code for the

```
<mongo:jmx />
```

element. Does this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to find the equivalent for beans created by any Spring XML parser, the first step is to look at the namespace handler, in this case `MongoNamespaceHandler`. Examining that class shows that the `jmx` namespace is parsed by the `MongoJmxParser`. Next step is to look at that and you'll see that it defines a bunch of beans; see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/MongoJmxParser.java#L47).

```
protected void registerJmxComponents(String mongoRefName, Element element, ParserContext parserContext) {
    Object eleSource = parserContext.extractSource(element);

    CompositeComponentDefinition compositeDef = new CompositeComponentDefinition(element.getTagName(), eleSource);

    createBeanDefEntry(AssertMetrics.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(BackgroundFlushingMetrics.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(BtreeIndexCounters.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(ConnectionMetrics.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(GlobalLockMetrics.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(MemoryMetrics.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(OperationCounters.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(ServerInfo.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);
    createBeanDefEntry(MongoAdmin.class, compositeDef, mongoRefName, eleSource, parserContext);

    parserContext.registerComponent(compositeDef);

}
```

Comment: Yes, when I create those beans manually, the MBeans show up in the JConsole. Thank you.